# Java variable with rest of substraction

Tags: java, math

I've got 2 integer values, e.g. a = 10 and b = 20.
Now i want to substract them: a - b, but as a result i don't want to have negative values, so in this example i want the result 0 and a new integer variable with the rest (10 here).

Two more examples:

- Input: a=40, b=20; Expected Output:20
- input: a=25 b=50 Expected Output: 0  and a new int var = 25

How to do this in java without external libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by a "new int var"? It's easy enough to get an absolute value; but your question is **unclear**.

Comment: This is so simple that I'm wondering why you're not able to just write down the Math formula first on a sheet of paper...obviously it's the maximum of 0 and the difference between a and b.

Comment: @AKSW, maybe he is just starting his way to learn programming and not certain about anything yet.

Comment: @joker well, but that's not about programming, isn't it? the first step is too formulate the problem: "the maximum of 0 and the difference between a and b" - this is pure math and not programming. anyways, he got answers that solve it in Java.

Comment: No problems in lending a hand for a newbie. His mind is not in order yet to know what to think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a variable to be holding the result if the result is greater than or equal to 0. Otherwise, that variable should hold 0 and another variable will hold a positive value of the result.

If this is the case, consider the following code snippet:

```
int result = a -b;
int otherVariable = 0;
if (result < 0) {
    otherVariable = -result;
    result = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int aMinusB = a-b;
int output = Math.max(aMinusB,0);
int rest = aMinusB < 0 ? Math.abs(aMinusB) : 0;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem: -

First: -

If you don't want to create a method to return this value and only to display it, then you can do it by printing out the results of if-else block in the code below within the function itself.

Second: -

If you want to use the result somewhere else, go for an object based approach: -

// Main class

```
public class SubtractWithRest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubtractResultWithRest subtractResultWithRest = new SubtractResultWithRest();
        subtraction(10, 20, subtractResultWithRest);
        System.out.println("Result: " + subtractResultWithRest.getResult());
        System.out.println("Rest: " + subtractResultWithRest.getRest());
    }

    private static void subtraction(int num1, int num2, SubtractResultWithRest subtractResultWithRest) {
        if (num2 > num1) {
            subtractResultWithRest.setResult(0);
            subtractResultWithRest.setRest(num2 - num1);
        } else {
            subtractResultWithRest.setResult(num1 - num2);
        }
    }

}
```

// Object class

```
public class SubtractResultWithRest {

    private int result;
    private int rest = 0;

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public int getRest() {
        return rest;
    }

    public void setRest(int rest) {
        this.rest = rest;
    }

}
```